# Springboot, JPA and Ignite

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, ignite

Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property save found for type Person!

Entity :

```
   @Entity

public class Person  implements Serializable {

     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
     @QuerySqlField(index = true)
     public Long id;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Repository

```
@Component
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "PersonCache")
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends IgniteRepository<Person, Long> {
     @Override
        List<Person> findAll();

        @Override
        Person findOne(Long id);

}
```

Ignite Configurations:

```
 @Bean
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        // Setting some custom name for the node.
        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("springDataNode");

        // Enabling peer-class loading feature.
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

        // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data repository.
        CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration("PersonCache");

        // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
        ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Person.class);


        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg);

        return Ignition.start(cfg);
    }
```

Stack trace:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property save found for type Person!  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:247)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:378)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:86)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.3.RELEASE.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]   ... 16 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: Why did you feel the need to have PersonRepository? Can you please share the whole reproducer on Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use IgniteRepository to work with a JPA entity.

I don't think that it's possible to marry these two. Spring JPA chokes on IgniteRepository custom methods trying to convert them into SQL, and even if it didn't it would still not work.

IgniteRepository was just not designed for JPA.