# how to solve Not a managed type exception?

Tags: spring-boot, ignite

I'm creating a spring boot app with apache ignite and im trying to store some values in cache but the response im getting is given below. can someone help?

```
---            
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'newRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.DTOname
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:826) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar:2.1.7.RELEASE]..
com.example.demo.ApacheIgniteHelloooApplication.main(ApacheIgniteHelloooApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]


            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.demo.model.DTOname
                at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
                at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  .          
---
```

this is the response I'm getting...after the ignite node starts.

this is my POJO class that i have used, and if I use an Entity class instead, i will get a no save method found error.
             ---
                public class DTOname implements Serializable {
                    private Integer  id;
                    private String name;
                    public Integer getId() {
                        return id;
                    }
                    public void setId(Integer id) {
                        this.id = id;
                    }
                   ............

```
        ---    


            this is my repository
        ---
            @RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "mycache")
            @Component
            @Repository
            public interface NewRepo extends IgniteRepository<DTOname, Integer> {

            }
         ---   

            this is my ignite config class
    ---
            @Configuration
            @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo.repository")
            @EnableIgniteRepositories        
            public class SpringDataConfig { 
                @Bean
                public Ignite igniteInstance() {
                    IgniteConfiguration config = new IgniteConfiguration();

                    CacheConfiguration cache = new CacheConfiguration("mycache");
                    cache.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class,DTOname.class);
                    config.setCacheConfiguration(cache);
                    return Ignition.start(config);
                }
            }
        ---
```

Comment: I don't think that Apache Ignite supports JPA, rather than 'vanilla' Spring Data.

Comment: Start here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921860/springboot-jpa-and-ignite

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot, JPA and Ignite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921860/springboot-jpa-and-ignite)

Comment: I'm new to ignite....can you guys ..plz suggest me a  way to add data to the cache  in (ignite+springboot)

Comment: @TJ32 You can use Data Streamer to add data to cache.